# How can I write a loop like this equation in GAMS?

Tags: math, optimization, gams-math, industrial

I tend to write some codes in GAMS that include a loop that exclude some indices ,how can I write some a loop like with exception?

```
u("p1","j1")*o1("p1","j2") - sum(t,v("p1","j1",t)*I1("p1","j2",t))=l=0;  
u("p1","j1")*o1("p1","j3") - sum(t,v("p1","j1",t)*I1("p1","j3",t))=l=0;
```

in these equations u , o together and also v,I1 together have different indices j;
how can write this loop?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to loop over and what the exceptions should be. Could you write up an example of what you want using pseudo code?

Comment: Dear Martin,assume this equations:u("p1","j1")*o1("p1","j2")-sum(t,v("p1","j1",t)*I1("p1","j2",t))=l=0;   I want to repeat this equation for all p,j in U,O1 in such a way u(p,j)!=o1(p,j),for example this loop do not consider u(p1,j1)*o1(p1,j1).but take into account u(p,j)*o1(o,j) except those u(p,j)=o1(p,j).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop, but probably a better solution is to limit the equations to the right combination of sets. In any case it can be done using alias of the sets and the SameAs operator.

```
Alias(p,pp);
Alias(j,jj);

E_myEquation(p,j,pp,jj)  $(not (SameAs(p,pp) and SameAs(j,jj)))..
    u(p,j)*o1(pp,jj) - sum(t, v(p,j,t)*I1(pp,jj,t)) =l= 0;
```

This defines the equation for all combinations of (p,j) with itself, except for (p,j)==(p,j).

I hope I have understood the request correctly, but otherwise you can probably figure out the exact implementation you want, using the Alias and SameAs functions.